# How do i manage certificates for xCode?

Tags: ios, xcode12

I'm having trouble when trying to build a unity build for ios in xCode.
So, my friend made an account and add me to the proyect. I'm in charge of making the build and testing it. But i'm getting errors about certificates. He built every certificates and send them back to me, I install them but i keep getting errors like:

- Provisioning profile " Proyect Name" doesn't include signing certificate "apple development: "My friend Certificate".
- No signing certificate "iOS Development" found. Here if i try to "Manage certificates" it says: No account for team "team number". But in my account information it says i'm part of said team.

I've try a lot of options from the internet but none of those solutions worked for me. Maybe we are doing something wrong with the team configuration or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your friend owns an individual developer account, his certificate won't work on your mac, unless his account logged in on your mac.

He can add you into the project for tester..etc. However, he can't grant you the same license.

If you only need to test and build, you can register your own apple id as personal developer. With this free developer license, you can at least build and test the app first. The build will be expired within 7 days in current policy, which means that you have to deploy the app into your device again when it expires.

When you are using different developer account for build, you have to change the certificate too. If someone already submitted the app with your existed package name, you will have to change the product name and package name for your testing too.

Comment: Thx for the answer! We will do it from his computer then.